# How to prevent iOS screenshot in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

In my application I want to disable screen shots function for IOS in React-native.

Please suggest me any working package or any native code which can disable screen shots in IOS.

Comment: Did you try FLAG_SECURE option

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the solutions by the library react native prevent screenshot:, check out the link [rn-screenshot](https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot)

> Overlay screen by added 2 two into appDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

// fill screen with our own colour
UIView *colourView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
colourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
colourView.tag = 1234;
colourView.alpha = 0;
[self.window addSubview:colourView];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:colourView];

// fade in the view
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
  colourView.alpha = 1;
}];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication \*)application {
// grab a reference to our coloured view
UIView \*colourView = [self.window viewWithTag:1234];
// fade away colour view from main view
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
colourView.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
// remove when finished fading
[colourView removeFromSuperview];
}];
}
```

Comment: This code does not work modern react-native version.

Comment: i havent implemnetd, but as you say , this doesnt work and maybe in ios you cant prevent